# Installing Ubuntu Linux and the Universal USB Installer does not show the disk to install on

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm following the youtube video to install `Ubuntu` as a dual-boot alongside with the Windows 8.1. I downloaded `Ubuntu` and `Universal USB Installer` and when I try to configure in `Universal USB Installer`, for `Step 3` it does not show any other drives except my `C:\` drive which contains `Windows 8.1`, and in the youtube videos they already have some `F:\UUI` or `G:\UUI` and etc. 
Can I install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 8.1 in `C:\` or how can I get other drives in `Step 3`? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: em... i doubt this is a suitable question for so.and the question is very specified to single software. but according to my knowledge, MS spent effort on preventing secondary OS installed on the same machine as win8, so i doubt you can make it. if you can do it in this way, why not try wubi? it's easier to uninstall(according to my experience, installing linux as secondary os will lead to giving-up in the future). perhaps VM is a better suit for you.

Comment: I've always used linux live usb to make my USB sticks from windows. http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ It seems to work.

Comment: Have you inserted USB drive while following this steps to create live usb? it seems you didn't.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish, do you mean to insert a physical USB flesh drive? Is it possible to create a separate drive to install Ubuntu on?

Answer (score 0):

Universal USB installer is not used to install ubuntu alongside windows. It is used to copy ubuntu installer and make a bootable pen driver. Then using that pendrive you install the ubuntu on your harddisk.

So **attach a pen drive to your system**, this pendrive will be shown in the list along with your C:, choose the pendrive and USB installer will make a bootable pendrive.

Comment: How can I attach a pen drive, @AnkitGoel ?

Answer (score 0):

Well to install ubuntu as dual boot alongside windows, here is a very brief idea about the steps to do it. You might need to change some of the settings (like UEFI), but it depends on your system.

1. Create a new partition (Any size that you want). Let it be unallocated space/unpartitioned space. (I mean don't create new partition out of it).
2. Next using any live USB installer (my preference are [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) or [LiLi USB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)), make your USB drive bootable.
3. Restart the system and live boot into your USB. (This step you might need to manually select one from boot manager, if your primary HDD is at first priority).

Now follow the steps from [Install Ubuntu after Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Here what you are trying to do is install an OS using a USB installer.